# Distinguishing cryptographic properties: hiding and collision resistance

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-collision

I saw from [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43360135/) the following definitions, which clarifies somewhat:

### Collision-resistance:

Given: x and h(x)

Hard to find: y that is distinct from x and such that h(y)=h(x).

### Hiding:

Given: h(r|x), where r|x is the concatenation of r and x

Secret: x and a highly-unlikely-and-randomly-chosen r

Hard to find: y such that h(y)=h(r|x). where r|x is the concatenation of r and x

This is different from collision-resistance in that it doesn’t matter whether or not y=r|x.

### My question:

Does this mean that any hash function h(x) is non-hiding if there is no secret r, that is, the hash is `h(x)`, not `h(r|x)`? where r|x is the concatenation of r and x

### Example:

Say I make a simple hash function `h(x) = g^x mod(n)`, where g is the generator for the group. The hash should be Collision resistant with `p(x_1 != x_2, h(x_1) = h(x_2)) = 1/(2^(n/2))`, but I would think it is hiding as well?

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes, I've edited for clarity

Comment: This is off-topic here; it clearly belongs on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashfunctions can kinda offer collision-resistance

Commitments have to be hiding.

In contrast to popular opinion these primitives are not the same!

Very strictly speaking the thing that you think of as hash-function cannot offer collision resistance: There always ARE collisions. The input space is infinite in theory, yet the function always produces a fixed-length output. The terminology should actually be “H is randomly drawn from a family of collision-resistant functions”. In practice however we will just call that function collision-resistant and ignore that it technically isn't.

A commitment has to offer two properties: Hiding and Binding. Binding means that you can only open it to one value (this is where the relation to collision-resistance comes in). Hiding means that it is impossible to learn anything about the element that is contained in it. This is why a secure commitment MUST use randomness (or nounces, but after all is said and done, those boil down to the same). Imagine any hash-function, no matter how perfect you want it to be: You can use a random-oracle if you want. If I give you a hash `H(m)` of a value `m` , you can compute `H(0)`, compare the result and learn whether `m = 0`, meaning it is not hiding.

This is also why `g^x` is not a hiding commitment-scheme. Whether it is binding depends on what you allow as the message-space: If you allow all integers, then a simple attack `y = x*phi(n)`produces `H(y)=H(x)`.
works. If you define it as `ℤ_p`, where `p` is the group-order, then it is perfectly binding, as it is an information-theoretically collision-resistant one-way-function. (Since message-space and target-space are of the same size, this time a single function actually CAN be truly collision-resistant!)